# What FPS subgenre is DOOM Eternal?

Tags: terminology, doom-eternal, genre-identification

I'm trying to figure out how to find more games similar to Doom 2016 and Doom Eternal. The problem is lots of google results seem to return FPS games like Call of Duty and Battlefield.

Although Call of Duty and Battlefield are also FPS games they play very differently from Doom. In Doom you basically run and shoot everything that moves without hiding behind cover or stealth. You have multiple weapons to upgrade to kill more enemies.

Wolfenstein games seem to fit the same category.

Does this genre have a name?

Comment: arcade-shooter, boomer-shooter, movement-shooter

Answer (score 3):

These kinds of games are often referred to as Arcade-style shooters. This genera of FPS games are, as you described, defined by their emphasis on movement instead of utilization of cover.

They have their roots in the original FPS games which existed before the use of cover, stealth, or other complex FPS mechanics were technologically feasible. In the case of DOOM and Wolfenstein these Arcade-style FPS roots are quite strong , as it these were some of the first breakout hits in the whole FPS genera.

Examples of these games also include Quake franchise, RAGE, DUSK, and even has some similarities with games like Overwatch which focus more on gameplay than realism.

Answer (score 2):

While it is slightly ironic to ask for the FPS subgenre of DOOM, the original predecessor of which defined the FPS genre itself, the genre has nonetheless 'evolved' dramatically, and increasingly incorporated elements from other genres, such as RPGs, that started to change our conception of *the* FPS.

The closest FPS subgenre DOOM Eternal would fall under seems to be [***'Boomer Shooter'***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooter_game#Boomer_shooter).
I've never heard of the [ridiculous name](https://www.pcgamer.com/what-should-boomer-shooters-be-called/) before, but it's apparently nothing obscure. The idea is that the classics that defined the genre—the original DOOM and Quake, Wolfenstein 3D—were popular under baby boomers. The problem is: they were more popular among their children, i.e. [Generation X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_X), or [Millennials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennials).
Anyway, the term encompasses all the original straightforward first-person shooter games and their contemporary clones.

You can also check for the terms [*DOOM clones*](https://doom.fandom.com/wiki/Doom_clones), [*retro (style) FPS*](https://macho-nacho.com/top-7-influential-retro-fps-games/), [*Twitch Shooter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitch_gameplay#Twitch_in_shooters), and [*golden era FPS*](https://80.lv/articles/a-book-on-quake-and-the-golden-age-of-fps/).

Comment: I think the thing the OP describes are really just mechanics of the game itself.  Doom Eternal is just... an FPS in my mind.  You just so happen to be a beast space marine.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I feel the game mechanics can strongly definite what genre a game is. It’s pretty clear that Escape from Tarkov plays  little like APEX legends, even though they’re both FPS games at their core

Comment: @TimmyJim Basic running and shooting without bells and whistles are characteristic for the classical FPS, but that term has become so diluted it needs specification. I think the terms mentioned describe that specific subgenre very clearly. (And ..thanks for the compliment?)